# How can I count the null entries by column in a kdb q table?

Tags: kdb

Given a table that contains a number of null entries how can I create a summary table that describes the number of nulls per column? Can this be done on a general table where the number of columns and column names are not known beforehand?

```
q)t: ([] a: 1 2 3 4; b: (2018.10.08; 0Nd; 2018.10.08; 2018.10.08); c: (0N;0N;30;40); d: `abc`def``jkl)
q)t
a b          c  d
-------------------
1 2018.10.08    abc
2               def
3 2018.10.08 30
4 2018.10.08 40 jkl
```

Expected result:

```
columnName nullCount
--------------------
a          0
b          1
c          2
d          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make such a table using

```
q)flip `columnName`nullCount!(key;value)@\:sum null t
columnName nullCount
--------------------
a          0
b          1
c          2
d          1
```

where `sum null t` gives a dictionary of the null values in each column

```
q)sum null t
a| 0
b| 1
c| 2
d| 1
```

and we apply the column names as keys and flip to a table.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - in the end I combined this answer with @terrylynch's extension to handle strings.

Answer (score 4):

While `sum null t` is the simplest solution in this example, it doesn't handle string (or nested) columns. To handle string or nested columns for example you would need something like

```
q)t: ([] a: 1 2 3 4; b: (2018.10.08; 0Nd; 2018.10.08; 2018.10.08); c: (0N;0N;30;40); d: `abc`def``jkl;e:("aa";"bb";"";()," "))
q){sum$[0h=type x;0=count@'x;null x]}each flip t
a| 0
b| 1
c| 2
d| 1
e| 1
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like an important extension! Why did you define the values of the string column as `("aa";"bb";"";()," ")` as apposed to `("aa";"bb";"";" ")`?

Comment: @RhysMartin in your example, the last item in the list is a char rather than a string (i.e. list of chars). In q, a string is a list of chars, so a list of strings is a list of lists, usually referred to as a nested list. Terry used `(),` to make a single character string; `enlist" "` would also be valid in this case. `(),` is often used when the following could be an atom or list & you need to ensure a list, without re-`enlist`ing something that is already a list

Comment: As Jonathon says, check `type each ("aa";"bb";"";()," ")` versus `type each ("aa";"bb";"";" ")`

Answer (score 1):

To produce a table with the columns as the headers and number of nulls and the values you can use:

```
q)tab:enlist sum null t
```

Which enlists a dictionary with the number of nulls as the values and the columns names as keys:

```
    a b c d
    -------
    0 1 2 1
```

If you then wanted this in your given format you could then use:

```
result:([]columnNames:cols tab; nullCount:raze value each tab)
```